SharePoint 2019 on-premises quick links COMPACT LAYOUT: all links open in new tab only!
I keep reading that quick links work the following way: external links open in new tab, internal links open in the same tab.
While that is true if I use the filmstrip layout, when I change the layout to COMPACT (which I need), then ALL links open in new window. What is that all about and is there any way to have the compact layout behave the same way as the filmstrip?
